# Is "turn comments" or "turning comments" an idiomatic way of responding to feedback?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I have a coworker who consistently says they are "turning comments" to mean "responding to feedback." In particular, it comes up in code review. Someone makes a comment, and the conversation has to be resolved before submitting. This person will say "I spent the day turning comments."

I had never heard this usage of "turn" before, nor had I heard the bigram "turn[ing] comments" used. I am struggling to find any similar usage on the internet either.

I assume that they did not just make this up...but I can't find which field or context they may have borrowed the expression from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all the references I can find to this term involve investment banking; it seems to be largely specific to that field. One definition is found in [this article from Bloomberg:](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2006-05-11/jammin-like-crazy-at-goldmanbusinessweek-business-news-stock-market-and-financial-advice#xj4y7vzkg)

> I return from the gym with an urgent voice mail describing some last-minute changes to the book we're preparing for tomorrow's meeting with the client. I take some notes and begin to quickly "turn the comments" -- banker lingo for making changes.

Comment: Here’s, perhaps, a fuller description: Unacceptable Investment Banking Analyst mistakes [relate to attention to detail. These include: Not incorporating all changes when “turning” comments (the changes that a senior member of the team gives you on a marked-up printout of your PowerPoint/Excel)*](http://sellsidehandbook.com/2017/07/22/get-decent-bonus-full-time-return-offer-part/)